# Why is my textBox_enter event (taking focus) called twice here?

Tags: c#, events, textbox

```
this.textBox1.Enter += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_Enter);

(...)

int test = 0;
private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ///
    /// update completion from db
    ///

    ++test;
    Log("got focus " + test);
}
```

I get this result from my log statements:

> [03/08/2013 13:56:40]: got focus 1
>   [03/08/2013 13:56:40]: got focus 2

Why is this function called twice each time I click in my text box?

I already checked: I have only one reference to this function.

Edit:

real function looks more like that

```
private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // update completion
    List<string> allValues = getValuesFromDb();
    myAutoComplete = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    myAutoComplete.AddRange(allValues.ToArray());
    textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = myAutoComplete; /// this line calls enter event again

    ++test;
    Log("got focus " + test);
}
```

Comment: Did you check Stack trace for both calls?

Comment: I do. What I should see inside ?

Comment: This should give you a clue about why it is called twice & who is calling it. Just drop a breakpoint inside your event handler & check the Stack trace in both calls.

Comment: Is first line from `InitializeComponent`? or you register for the event handler manually?

Comment: he probably registered twice for the event.

Comment: @AdelKhayata, thanks I got it: textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = ...

Comment: so that not very nice from dot net

Comment: so now, how to prevent it ?

Comment: if my guess is correct just delete your own subscribing ,i bet inside initializecomponent there is already some line like this.textbox1.enter += new System.EventHandler(this.textBox1_Enter)

Comment: @terrybozzio, thanks but bad bet. Reassign AutoCompleteCustomSource is the cause. If I comment the recording event line program does not pass thru the enter method.

Comment: enter event looks best momment to update completion. I'm stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

question solved I know why. calling :

```
textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = myCustomSource;
```

call *enter event* again.

So now how to prevent it ?

1) (not working) first solution: move the following piece of code elsewhere

```
textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource =...
```

not good: autocompletion is not updated

2) (working) put a lock as

```
 int test = 0;
 bool lockEnter = false;
 private void textBox1_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
  if (!lockEnter)
  {
    lockEnter = true;

    // update completion
    List<string> allValues = getValuesFromDb();
    myAutoComplete = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    mtAutoComplete.AddRange(allValues.ToArray());
    textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = myAutoComplete;

    ++test;
    Log("update completion " + test);

    lockEnter = false;
  }
```

}

give result excepted.

Thanks you guys !